# Why is this causing an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Both these code blocks should be doing the same thing. The first code block works as I would expect, and does not go into an infinite loop, but the second code block does.

```
contig = deque()
contig.append(2)
answer = 0
while contig:
    dist = contig.popleft()
    val = 0
    while pow(2, val) < dist:
        val += 1
    if pow(2, val) == dist:
        answer += 1
        val = 0
    elif pow(2, val) > dist:
        answer += 1
        contig.append(dist - pow(2, val - 1))
        val = 0
```

```
contig = deque()
contig.append(2)
answer = 0
while contig:
    dist = contig.popleft()
    val = 0
    total = pow(2, val)
    while total < dist:
        #print(total)
        #print(val)
        val += 1
    if total == dist:
        answer += 1
        val = 0
    elif total > dist:
        answer += 1
        contig.append(dist - pow(2, val - 1))
        val = 0
```

for the second code block, val keeps printing the updated value + 1, but total remains the same. Why would total remain the same in this case? I can see that total remains 1, but should it not be taking on total = pow(2*val) with val being the new value?

Comment: Because `total = pow(2, val)` sets the value of `total` one time and never updates it again. The expression is evaluated right there and not constantly.

Comment: mad physicist, is the case across all programming languages or is this python specific?, i noticed this also happend when I tried this with multiplicaiton, but its weird to me that when you try this with one expression, it updates but when combined it would not?

Comment: I'm not sure where you've seen an expression that sets up a permanent relationship

Comment: you're right in no world does that exist, so is this a pass by reference vs value thing or?

Comment: It's not that at all. It's like saying that if I give you $1 for an apple right now, I'll give you $1 every time you have an apple. The processor runs what you tell it to, when you tell it.

Comment: could you please reopen this question so I can get a better explanation? I don't see how the link that is linked relates to this. Your explanation also isn't making sense to me because for the line  "while total < dist: " should the compiler not check what the value of total is? Why does it just assume it is one every time, that statement does get evaluated somewhere right?

Comment: Neither total nor dist changes in the inner loop. Put a breakpoint or a print statement. You'll understand much better by seeing it in action

Comment: I'm not going to reopen because it's the same exact concept. At some point, you're responsible for making the effort to learn